# Static pages without using at the end the ".html" at the URLs

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

I have created a new site using HTML and I want to change it with an existing Joomla.

So for example the URL is `www.example.com` and there is the Joomla. I created a Joomla directory and put everything there and then I placed the new HTML files at the root directory. But if you don't type `www.example.com/index.html` the new website can't be accessed.

So what do I have to do in order to type `www.example.com` and the `index.html` is showing by default?

Comment: Make changes in web.config file to redirect the website to the page you want by default OR add a redirect using hosting panel

Comment: The thing is i have ftp access, no web panel. I have read here http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F
about .htaccess file and redirect to specific html file with: 

# Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)
DirectoryIndex index.html

But the .htaccess file will have only this line?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant .htaccess. Yeah give it a try and see what happens. I'm not too sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write what worked for me. I 've read this http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/change-default-page-for-domain.shtml

So I have put the joomla in a directory, and moved the static pages in the root folder. I renamed the html page that i wanted for the default home page to "index.html" and it worked without any scripting or htaccess.